# Cassandra 2.1.2 node stuck on joining the cluster

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying but failing to join a new (well old, but wiped out) node to an existing cluster.

Currently cluster consists of 2 nodes and runs C* 2.1.2. I start a third node with 2.1.2, it gets to joining state, it bootstraps, i.e. streams some data as shown by nodetool netstats, but after some time, it gets stuck. From that point nothing gets streamed, the new node stays in joining state. I restarted node twice, everytime it streamed more data, but then got stuck again. (I'm currently on a third round like that).

Other facts:

- I don't see any errors in the log on any of the nodes.
- The connectivity seems fine, I can ping, netcat to port 7000 all ways.
- I have 267 GB load per running node, replication 2, 16 tokens.
- Load of a new node is around 100GBs now
- I'm guessing that the node after few rounds of restarts, will finally suck in all of the data from running nodes and join the cluster. But definitely it's not the way it should work.

EDIT:  I discovered some more info:

- The bootstrapping process stops in the middle of streaming some table, **always** after sending exactly 10MB of some SSTable, e.g.:

  `$ nodetool netstats | grep -P -v "bytes\(100"
  Mode: NORMAL
  Bootstrap e0abc160-7ca8-11e4-9bc2-cf6aed12690e
      /192.168.200.16
          Sending 516 files, 124933333900 bytes total
              /home/data/cassandra/data/leadbullet/page_view-2a2410103f4411e4a266db7096512b05/leadbullet-page_view-ka-13890-Data.db 10485760/167797071 bytes(6%) sent to idx:0/192.168.200.16
  Read Repair Statistics:
  Attempted: 2016371
  Mismatch (Blocking): 0
  Mismatch (Background): 168721
  Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
  Commands                        n/a         0       55802918
  Responses                       n/a         0         425963`

I can't diagnose the error & I'll be grateful for any help!

Comment: Have you been watching the JVM during the join? Is the heap fully utilized and do you see any long GC's occurring in the C* logs?

Comment: Did you decommission the node before adding it back in? Gossip occasionally remembers nodes and causes trouble when the node is added back in later.

Comment: @RussS, yes I watched it. And it looks pretty fine. The heap usage gets to max, but then it gets properly CMS'ed to 1GB.

Comment: @mildewey, I did decommission the node before adding it back in.

Comment: @zarzyk have you checked your system.log? are there any unusual messages?

Comment: @JacekL., yes, I looked into system.log, in DEBUG mode. I saw that streaming of the sstable starts but it never ends and I see no error. Of course it maybe just me not knowing what to look for...

Comment: @zarzyk one more thing - try to look into operating system log

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to telnet from one node to another using correct port.
2. Make sure you are joining the correct name cluster.
3. Try use: nodetool repair
4. You might be pinging the external IP addressed, and your cluster communicates using internal IP addresses.
5. If you are running on Amazon AWS, make sure you have firewall open on both  internal IP addresses.